# if I was sick , and needed someone to give me water , should I say : water me ?

Tags: grammar

I mean not just giving me water , I need them to put the cup on my lips ... etc ? I know : water the grass .

Comment: To water is generally used for flowers and animals, not humans. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/water

Comment: You can ask, *can you help me drink some water, please.*

Comment: You could say it but it's *extremely* informal and would only sound normal if the person was handing out bottled water or something of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

Can I get some water?
This one is better.